# How does matchmaking work in MTG Arena?

Tags: magic-the-gathering-arena

Presumably the ranked play options match people based on their rank. Even then I know that isn't really true because I've been matched up with people of different ranks judging by the emblems next to their names. This happened more often at lower ranks to me which is particularly interesting considering I'd expect there to be more people at lower ranks...

The matchmaking algorithm is even less clear to me for unranked matches since my ability as a player playing a deck/hand is distinct from my ability to form a powerful deck, and both of those skill sets don't really matter if the deck/player combination I'm playing against can effectively counter my deck. All of this makes for difficult matchmaking, so do we know or have any clues as to how they do their matchmaking?

---

Anecdotally it feels like as I play longer my wins become more infrequent. It also feels like if I drop money into the game I also win more frequently. I don't have any hard data to support these observations. So this perception might just be driven by losses stinging more. Regardless this perception has been bothering me while I play.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody really has any hard evidence for how the matchmaking algorithms work, but I've always been matching with people my rank when it comes to ranked play. It could be that there are less new people than there used to be, so it might start matching you with someone "close enough" if it takes a while, like many other multiplayer games do.

When it comes to unranked play, I think the game still matches you with people around your level. What you felt could've just been you leveling up and slowly starting to play with people that understand the game, but it's still hard to tell if easy wins are intentional or not because unranked play is *usually* full of people that are just trying new decks and losing quickly.